# How to get Text Widget Code over Wordpress Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, sidebar

Recently i have a requirement from client as he want dynamic sidebar (Text-Widget) content show over the Home Page. So, what ever he enter into text box i.e Link, Image or Text that should be come up over home page.

Can anybody give me hint to show Widget Content over Home or any Page?

Comment: make a sidebar that displays on the homepage. But this can be done better on a page.... Why use a text widget?

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/)

This plugin gives every widget an extra control field called "Widget logic" that lets you control the pages that the widget will appear on. The text field lets you use WP's Conditional Tags, or any general PHP code.